# struts2: default parameter generated by s:url tag

Tags: struts2

In struts2 we use

```
<action name="anAction">
    <result name="success">xx.jsp</result>
</action>
```

to define action, and use s:url to generate a link to the action

```
<s:url action="anAction"></s:url>
```

The above s:url will output "/anAction.do".

I wonder if it's possible to let `s:url` generate a default URL parameter (i.e. `/anAction.do?p=xxx` for all links), without modifying the existing `s:url` tags (there are many and they are scattered). The goal is to let the parameter appear in the link for SEO purpose.

Available options can be: changing any action config, changing any struts config, even rewrite the `s:url` generation class.

Edit: I found that adding this to `struts.xml`

```
<constant name="struts.url.includeParams" value="get" />
```

partially solves my problem (as long as the initial page has ?p=xxx, all subsequent links will have it). The short-comings are obvious: the parameter will not follow a redirect action. I am still searching for more sophisticated solution.

Comment: **[Redirect Result](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/redirect-result.html)** : `<result type="redirect"><param>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did figure out how this can be done.  The steps are:

1) create a class which implements org.apache.struts2.components.UrlRenderer
2) register that class with struts object factory and it will be injected as necessary

Details? Ok.

1) For example, a subclass of ServletUrlRender might look like this:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer;
import org.apache.struts2.components.UrlProvider;

public class ParameterInjectingUrlRenderer extends ServletUrlRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void mergeRequestParameters(String value, Map<String, Object> parameters, Map<String, Object> contextParameters) {
       super.mergeRequestParameters(value, parameters, contextParameters);
       parameters.put("myParameter", "secretvalue");
    }
}
```

2) In struts.xml, set this class as the renderer implementation, with a line like this:

```
<constant name="struts.urlRenderer" value="parameterInjectingUrlRenderer" />
```

(In this example I'm using a Spring object factory, and value references a spring bean id. If you are not, I believe you put the fully-qualified class name).

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Global Search and replace (All IDE's should have this feature)

```
<s:url action="anAction"></s:url>
```

With

```
<s:url action="anAction"><s:param name="p" value="'xxx'"/></s:url>
```

Now every "anAction" will have a parameter p with value xxx.

It generally a good idea to specify the namespace.

```
<s:url namespace="/" action="anAction"><s:param name="p" value="'xxx'"/></s:url>
```

Comment: Hi Quaternion thanks so much for the reply however, what I need to  achieve is under the prerequisite "without modifying the existing s:url tags". Your approach works fine but it requires all future developer to *remember* to add the same s:param to s:url by ctrl-cv, hence a violation of DRY.

Comment: Providing your own s:url implementation is probably the only way to go. I'd create a service that would fetch from a db, the dummy values you wanted to add to the url.  Table fields: id (auto increment), namespace, action, parameterName, value.  And then glue on any parameters for the values it found for the particular namspace/action. If you solved I'd upvote the solution!

Comment: Just FYI, I looked a providing my own `<s:url/>` implementation and it looks quite painful AND I believe it wouldn't override s:url but you could do `<my:url/>` instead, which is still a global search&replace.